# Samsung Galaxy - Import contacts from sbu file

Tags: contacts, backup, samsung-kies, restore

I'd a Samsung Galaxy i551. I've done a backup using Kies and it saved a .sbu file. Now I don't have the phone any more and I'd like to export this information to some useful format or at least to view it with the Kies. But I can't find anyway to open the .sbu file.

How do I open an .sbu file generated by Kies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=983471) over at XDA-Developers forum. Someone wrote a Java app to extract the contacts out of the .sbf file into VCard files, which are a lot easier to deal with.

Also, in the same thread people report that with the [latest version of Kies](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201105/20110512115717796/Kies_2.0.3.11082_152_2.exe) you can execute a Restore without having a Samsung phone connected to the PC, and extract the contents.

I personally haven't tried either method, so please let us know if they work for you.

Comment: I couldn't find the way to open the .sbu with the Samsung Kies (not even with the version you linked). But the java app worked great!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program which extracts contacts and Calendar Data.

https://lord-luncher.de/

I am happy about feedback.

Comment: A step-by-step tutorial with some pictures would be nice

Answer (score 0):

in the latest version o Kies you select your device in the tree, then go to tab "back up/restore" and click "restore".

Unfortunately you can't restore just something, you should restore everything...