# Extracting data from a backup file (.sbu) made by Samsung kies

Tags: samsung-kies, restore

I had made a back up file containing contacts, , calender, memo etc with the help of Samsung kies which was saved in .sbu format when I owned a Galaxy ace plus. But now I have a new phone galaxy grand quattro and have updated the kies software.
Now the kies software does not show any calender, memo etc which can be restored on my new device.
please help me out with this problem.

Comment: Possibly related: [Samsung Galaxy - Import contacts from sbu file](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15653/samsung-galaxy-import-contacts-from-sbu-file)

Answer (score 1):

Try Smart Switch with this you can easily transfer your backup from your old device to new device with ease.

Check this [link](http://www.samsung.com/ae/support/smartswitch/).
You must have the old backup folder in your C:/ drive under the Kies folder/backup.

**Note**-If you deleted this wanted/accidentally done then you have lost your backup and cannot transfer any backup.
Next time onwards please store your backup files in a folder known to you in this way you can open the folder and directly send the backup anytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found that running Kies Restore does a seemingly complete .sbu file extraction to a temporary directory such as:

`C:\Users\{LogonName}\Documents\samsung\Kies\sbu\te mp\{NumberID}\{Files Extracted}`

One can copy the files from there.